# How to launch Windows Live Photo Gallery Screensaver in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

How can I create a link that stars the Photo Gallery screensaver AND uses the images from the path "C:\Users\John\Desktop\stuff".

I can create a link to start the screensaver, but its showing images from the wrong directory. How can I pass the photos path to the screensaver?

This is the link target...
%SystemRoot%\system32\photoscreensaver.scr /s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screensaver most probably takes its settings from the Registry, not from a command-line parameter.

It's showing pictures from the directory defined in its Settings.

Comment: Snark, thanks! you're right, these config values are stored in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread topic regarding this matter...

http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/59487-photoscreensaver-scr-command-line-parameters.html

Here is a solution posted in the thread...

> Found the Fix!!!
>
> 1. Searched procmon.log to confirm if the FolderPath key (which determines the location of the pictures) was being read. The log showed that the key that was being searched was:
>
> "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\Slideshow\Screensaver"
>
> instead of:
>
> "HKEY_USERS.Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\Slideshow\Screensaver"
>
> 2. Added the "Windows Photo Gallery" registry keys to the Local Service account
>      (S-1-5-19) and the screensaver started to work"

However, a simpler way to change the settings (that doesn't involve editing the registry)...

1. Right click on the Photos Screensaver link.
2. Click 'configure'.
3. A settings dialog will open, with options to set the photos path and play speed.